# Global feature importance in XGBoost R using SHAP values

Tags: r, xgboost

I would like to know if there is a method to compute global feature importance in R package of XGBoost using SHAP values instead of GAIN like Python package of SHAP. 
I mean, in XGBoost for Python there is a function to compute SHAP values at global level making the mean absolute of the SHAP value for each feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
shap_contrib <- predict(model,newdata,predcontrib=T)
```

in order to get the `SHAP` values directly from `XGBoost`.

Once you get that, it's just a matter of doing:

```
mean_shap <- colMeans(abs(shap_contrib))
```

Comment: for a classification model, I get: "Error in abs(xgb_preds) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function"